# How to disable _PHCR key pefixes used in Phalcon Redis backend

Tags: php, redis, phalcon

I'm using Phalcon Redis backend to store some data. I later try to access this data in Lua language embedded into nginx. What drives me crazy is that Phalcon adds some garbage prefixes to Redis keys and some terrible prefixes to values. So, if I store this pair in Redis - (abc, querty) - this is what is really stored:

```
(_PHCRabc, s:6:"querty")
```

Is it possible to disable all this garbage and continue working with Phalcon Redis backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the the source it is not possible to disable it with option: https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/phalcon/cache/backend/redis.zep

```
public function get(string keyName, int lifetime = null) -> var | null
   let lastKey = "_PHCR" . prefix . keyName;

public function save(keyName = null, content = null, lifetime = null, boolean stopBuffer = true) -> boolean
   lastKey = "_PHCR" . prefixedKey,
```

Also quoting **[the docs](https://olddocs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.2/api/Phalcon_Cache_Backend_Redis.html)**:

> This adapter uses the special redis key “_PHCR” to store all the keys
>   internally used by the adapter

I read somewhere that this is done in order to be able to flush Phalcon generated cache files.

Your best option would be to extend the `\Phalcon\Cache\Backend\Redis` class and overwrite the save/get methods. And after use your class in the service:

```
// Cache
$di->setShared('cache', function() use ($config) {
    return new MyCustomRedis(
        new \Phalcon\Cache\Frontend\Json(['lifetime' => 172800]), // 2d
        $config->redis
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the redis adapter like this.

```
<?php

namespace App\Library\Cache\Backend;

use Phalcon\Cache\Exception;

class Redis extends \Phalcon\Cache\Backend\Redis
{

    /**
     * @var \Redis
     */
    protected $_redis;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @param  string $keyName
     * @param  integer $lifetime
     * @return mixed|null
     */
    public function get($keyName, $lifetime = null)
    {
        $redis = $this->getRedis();

        /**
         * @var \Phalcon\Cache\FrontendInterface $frontend
         */
        $frontend = $this->_frontend;
        $lastKey = $this->getKeyName($keyName);

        $this->_lastKey = $lastKey;

        $content = $redis->get($lastKey);

        if ($content === false) {
            return null;
        }

        if (is_numeric($content)) {
            return $content;
        }

        return $frontend->afterRetrieve($content);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @param  string $keyName
     * @param  string $content
     * @param  int $lifetime
     * @param  bool $stopBuffer
     * @return bool
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function save($keyName = null, $content = null, $lifetime = null, $stopBuffer = true)
    {
        if ($keyName === null) {
            $lastKey = $this->_lastKey;
        } else {
            $lastKey = $this->getKeyName($keyName);
            $this->_lastKey = $lastKey;
        }

        if (!$lastKey) {
            throw new Exception('The cache must be started first');
        }

        $redis = $this->getRedis();

        /**
         * @var \Phalcon\Cache\FrontendInterface $frontend
         */
        $frontend = $this->_frontend;

        if ($content === null) {
            $cachedContent = $frontend->getContent();
        } else {
            $cachedContent = $content;
        }

        /**
         * Prepare the content in the frontend
         */
        if (!is_numeric($cachedContent)) {
            $preparedContent = $frontend->beforeStore($cachedContent);
        } else {
            $preparedContent = $cachedContent;
        }

        if ($lifetime === null) {
            $tmp = $this->_lastLifetime;
            $ttl = $tmp ? $tmp : $frontend->getLifetime();
        } else {
            $ttl = $lifetime;
        }

        $success = $redis->set($lastKey, $preparedContent);

        if (!$success) {
            throw new Exception('Failed storing the data in redis');
        }

        if ($ttl > 0) {
            $redis->setTimeout($lastKey, $ttl);
        }

        $isBuffering = $frontend->isBuffering();

        if ($stopBuffer === true) {
            $frontend->stop();
        }

        if ($isBuffering === true) {
            echo $cachedContent;
        }

        $this->_started = false;

        return $success;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @param  string $keyName
     * @return bool
     */
    public function delete($keyName)
    {
        $redis = $this->getRedis();

        $lastKey = $this->getKeyName($keyName);

        return (bool)$redis->delete($lastKey);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @param  string $prefix
     * @return array
     */
    public function queryKeys($prefix = null)
    {
        $redis = $this->getRedis();

        $pattern = "{$this->_prefix}" . ($prefix ? $prefix : '') . '*';

        return $redis->keys($pattern);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @param  string $keyName
     * @param  string $lifetime
     * @return bool
     */
    public function exists($keyName = null, $lifetime = null)
    {
        $redis = $this->getRedis();

        if ($keyName === null) {
            $lastKey = $this->_lastKey;
        } else {
            $lastKey = $this->getKeyName($keyName);
        }

        return (bool)$redis->exists($lastKey);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @param string $keyName
     * @param int $value
     * @return int
     */
    public function increment($keyName = null, $value = 1)
    {
        $redis = $this->getRedis();

        if ($keyName === null) {
            $lastKey = $this->_lastKey;
        } else {
            $lastKey = $this->getKeyName($keyName);
        }

        return $redis->incrBy($lastKey, $value);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @param string $keyName
     * @param int $value
     * @return int
     */
    public function decrement($keyName = null, $value = 1)
    {
        $redis = $this->getRedis();

        if ($keyName === null) {
            $lastKey = $this->_lastKey;
        } else {
            $lastKey = $this->getKeyName($keyName);
        }

        return $redis->decrBy($lastKey, $value);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function flush()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Get Prefix
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPrefix()
    {
        return $this->_prefix;
    }

    /**
     * Get Redis Connection
     *
     * @return \Redis
     */
    public function getRedis()
    {
        $redis = $this->_redis;

        if (!is_object($redis)) {
            $this->_connect();
            $redis = $this->_redis;
        }

        return $redis;
    }

    /**
     * Get Key Name
     *
     * @param $keyName
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getKeyName($keyName)
    {
        return $this->_prefix . $keyName;
    }

}
```